# How to renumber the observations based on the value of a column

Tags: r, bigdata, categories, data-manipulation

Below is the simplified example of my data, the column `new` is the one I want to add to the dataset. Basically, I want to rename the `riskset` using 1,2,3,4... so that it'll be easier for me to do loops. The numbers in `riskset` have been sorted, they are not continuous and there are duplicate numbers in the `riskset` (10~11 for each unique number), so how to add another column grouping the observations based on their `riskset` number?

```
  riskset            new
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3
              ......
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple base R solution would be to use `factor`s and then cast `as.integer`

```
as.integer(as.factor(df$riskset))
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3
```

Or since you've asked for a `dplyr` option

```
df %>% mutate(new = as.integer(as.factor(riskset)))
```

or the base R equivalent using `transform`

```
transform(df, new = as.integer(as.factor(riskset)))
```

Another option is to use `dplyr::lag` and `cumsum`

```
df %>% mutate(new = cumsum(riskset != lag(riskset, default = T)) + 1)
```

Or since you mentioned `group_by` you could do

```
df %>% group_by(riskset) %>% group_indices()
```

to generate the group indices.

`group_indices` also works within `mutate`

```
df %>% group_by(riskset) %>% mutate(new = group_indices())
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "  riskset            new
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000017          1
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000066          2
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3
a.0000000099          3", header = T)
```